# SPARQL Query Assistance

Tags: sparql, ontology

I need help trying to translate a DL query into a SPARQL query, please. I have looked everywhere, but I am just struggling to understand SPARQL.

I want to look for a specialist that is able to do R and works in the Statistics Field.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ?Specialist ?Field
    WHERE {?Specialist ont:hasSkill ont:R .}
```

Comment: are you looking for individuals fulfilling this concept or for subclasses?

Comment: for the former: `SELECT ?Specialist ?Field WHERE {?Specialist ont:hasSkill ont:R ; ont:hasField ?Field . ?Field a ont:Statistics . }` - it's not clear if in your instance data you use the class `Statistics` as an individual or if you have individuals belonging to the class `Statistics`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.